# "compiling" stacktrace error for clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure, and I find difficult to understand *where* a specific compiler error happens:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to 
clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection, compiling:(fwpd/core.clj:100:1)
```

Line 100 is just:

```
(fib-seq3 5)
```

So it says nothing, because in fact the error is in the fib-seq3 function (parameters to a "conj" call are inverted, see below).

Is this normal? No way to know where an error is???

Just for reference, here's the code (again, **I know where the error is**; I just don't understand how was I supposed to find it, given that the message doesn't tell me at which line it happens):

```
(defn fib-seq3
  ([to]
   (fib-seq3 [] 0 1 0 to))
  ([coll a b k to]
    (if (= k to)
      coll
      (fib-seq3 (conj b coll) b (+ a b) (inc k) to)))

(fib-seq3 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I was using REPL (Vim+Fireplace) to execute the code. Executing using `lein repl` fixed the problem.

@Leonid @amalloy:

`(.printStackTrace *e)`

gives the proper stacktrace in the REPL (even from inside Fireplace, using "cqp" which gives the REPL prompt), so **thank you very much** for the comment (didn't know that!)

Answer (score 3):

Stack traces in Clojure suck. In fact, [error messages were rated by Clojure community as the top priority area for improvements, as well as Clojure most frustrating part](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2016/1/28/state-of-clojure-2015-survey-results).

This problem is not new. There was no considerable improvements in Clojure stack traces for quite a long time. But Clojure team is fully aware of this situation, so we could hope for improvements.

To better understand Clojure stack traces try reading [Clojure Stack Traces for the Uninitiated](https://blog.8thlight.com/connor-mendenhall/2014/09/12/clojure-stacktraces.html). Though the article is somewhat old, it's still relevant.

In short, you should look for so-called "cause trace", which is a second part of any Clojure stack trace and starts with "Caused by" phrase.

Comment: my problem is not understanding the error; it's understanding **where** the error is. in [Clojure Stack Traces for the Uninitiated](https://blog.8thlight.com/connor-mendenhall/2014/09/12/clojure-stacktraces.html) he gets a proper stack trace:  `at stacktraces.core$make_sandwich.invoke(core.clj:4)
   at stacktraces.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:7)` while I get the error on the calling function line... not on the called!

Comment: @Leo are you running your code in REPL? Clojure REPL usually prints only a root-cause of your exception. You could use `(print-cause-trace *e)` from `clojure.stacktrace` namespace to print full cause trace.

Comment: I strongly recommend using `(.printStackTrace *e)` if you're running in a repl that truncates stacktraces by default. Don't mess with print-cause-trace: every layer of tooling you insert between yourself and your stacktraces is one more thing that can go wrong, at a point when things have already gone wrong.